# What scale should I resize images on Mac retina to look normal on Windows

Tags: macos, mac, images, macbook-pro-retina

I am on OS X with Retina - chosen setting `1680 x 1050`, the one after *Best (Retina)*

When I open an image in preview `800 x 600 res`., Retina display upscales it and it looks bigger than it actually is. I don't know whats the DPI of the image.

But when I take a screenshot from Mac, say a small area (which is actually `1060 × 560`), it also is almost of the same size **in looks**.

Now when I change the DPI of the screenshot to 72, Mac thinks that its a normal image and upscales it for Display.

So when I view both the files on Windows (both are 72 DPI), they look bigger or smaller as per their pixel value.

But my original intention was that the small area which I took screenshot of, should stay small on Windows. Which means I will have to resize the screenshot with diff. `width x height` pixels, on the same DPI.

How can I determine the resize factor/scale of Screenshots to be transferred to Windows, given my current setting on Mac Retina.

Answer (score 0):

It's twice the "normal" size.  There are a few apps (both commercial and free) that can "right size" your screen captures (I tried Retina Capture with decent success).

If you want a DIY solution that works well, [check out this blog post on Lance's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114213223/http://blog.lanceli.com/2012/08/downscale-screenshot-at-hight-resolution-on-retina-mackbook-pro.html) for a home grown solution that you can integrate with <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> using Keyboard shortcuts in SysPref.

Comment: Site no longer working :-(

Comment: @dbreaux I replaced the dead link with an archived copy (when my edit gets approved).